# Total bytes for each IPs in the dataset using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, networking, data-science

```
df.value_counts(subset='DstAddr', ascending=False)
```

[image]

```
df.head()
```

[image]

I am trying to find a way to show for each unique IP:
How many in the sum of total bytes does it have?
For example, if I want to find all dataset:

```
df['TotBytes'].sum()
```

But I want to find for each destination unique IP to see how much KB it is used for that IP.

Comment: `df.groupby("DstAddr")` and work with groups - something like `df.groupby("DstAddr")['TotBytes'].sum()` or using `for key, val in df.groupby("DstAddr"): print( val['TotBytes'].sum() )`

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: When I try to copy the output of .head() from jupyter notebook, the data looks so messy. That is why I put a screenshot. Maybe there is an easier way, I am sorry. Let me try to edit my question.

Comment: maybe if you put in ```  code/data ``` then it should look good. OR you should display as text `df.to_string()` and it should give pure text without HTML formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `df.groupby("DstAddr")` to work with groups - something like

```
df.groupby("DstAddr")['TotBytes'].sum()
```

or using loop

```
for key, val in df.groupby("DstAddr"): 
    print(key, val['TotBytes'].sum() )
```

---

Minimal working example

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': ['1.0.0.0','2.0.0.0','3.0.0.0', '2.0.0.0',], 
    'B': [4,5,6,7], 
    'C': [7,8,9,0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

print(df.groupby('A')['B'].sum())

for key, val in df.groupby('A'):
    print('---', key, '---')
    print(val['B'].sum())
```

Result:

```
         A  B  C
0  1.0.0.0  4  7
1  2.0.0.0  5  8
2  3.0.0.0  6  9
3  2.0.0.0  7  0

A
1.0.0.0     4
2.0.0.0    12
3.0.0.0     6
Name: B, dtype: int64

--- 1.0.0.0 ---
4
--- 2.0.0.0 ---
12
--- 3.0.0.0 ---
6
```